# Stuck on black loading screen after cinematic for "The Devil by the Well" contract

Tags: ps4, the-witcher-3

I am on the Witcher contract "The Devil by the Well".

I have done all required investigation, and when I do the final step (putting the bracelet with the corpse to burn it), after the cinematic my screen turns black.

The game keeps loading from then, and doesn't get back to the game.

I have tried several things to sort this out:

- I cleaned the disc (despite it being a new disc)
- I turned my PS4 off and restarted it and had the same issue.

I don't know what I should do next, someone advised me to delete it and reinstall it, but I'm afraid to lose my save game.

Please if someone has a good solution I would appreciate it so much.

Comment: If it's any help, you won't lose your save game by reinstalling the game. You might try reloading a save from a little earlier and going from there, in case it is a glitch with your current game?